# Something wrong with using add on list

Tags: c#, list, class, addition

**Update#1:** 
These are the changes I have made, but none of them works:

1) remove static

```
string date;
string title;
string description;
string organizer;
string place;
```

2) make tempe local

```
events tempe = new events();
tempe.setDate(event_info[0]);
tempe.setTitle(event_info[1]);
tempe.setPlace(event_info[2]);
tempe.setDesc(event_info[3]);
tempe.setOrganizer(event_info[4]);
eventsarray.Add(tempe);
tempe = null;
```

3) use the list directly

```
eventsarray.Add(new events());
eventsarray[eventsarray.Count - 1].setDate(event_info[0]);
eventsarray[eventsarray.Count - 1].setTitle(event_info[1]);
eventsarray[eventsarray.Count - 1].setPlace(event_info[2]);
eventsarray[eventsarray.Count - 1].setDesc(event_info[3]);
eventsarray[eventsarray.Count - 1].setOrganizer(event_info[4]);
```

---

**Original question**

I am trying to store a list of events into a list, but when I try to add new event, all other instances of event in the list also got replaced by the last input.
The codes below contains the process of storing new event into the list by using .Add, enclosed by 3 groups of codes providing output for the purpose of debug.

```
if (eventsarray.Count > 0)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "Before Insert: \r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray.Count: " + eventsarray.Count.ToString() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[0].getDate: " + eventsarray[0].getDate() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[0].getTitle: " + eventsarray[0].getTitle() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[0].getPlace: " + eventsarray[0].getPlace() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[0].getDesc: " + eventsarray[0].getDesc() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[0].getOrganizer: " + eventsarray[0].getOrganizer() + "\r\n\r\n";
}


//store all into into a new event in eventsarray

tempe.setDate(event_info[0]);
tempe.setTitle(event_info[1]);
tempe.setPlace(event_info[2]);
tempe.setDesc(event_info[3]);
tempe.setOrganizer(event_info[4]);
//something is wrong with .Add?
eventsarray.Add(tempe);


if (eventsarray.Count > 0)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "After Insert: \r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray.Count: " + eventsarray.Count.ToString() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[0].getDate: " + eventsarray[0].getDate() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[0].getTitle: " + eventsarray[0].getTitle() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[0].getPlace: " + eventsarray[0].getPlace() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[0].getDesc: " + eventsarray[0].getDesc() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[0].getOrganizer: " + eventsarray[0].getOrganizer() + "\r\n\r\n";
}
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray.Count: " + eventsarray.Count.ToString() + "\r\n";
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "Event " + event_info[1] + " has been added to List." + "\r\n\r\n";

for (int i = 0; i < eventsarray.Count; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "Looping: "+ i.ToString()  + "\r\n" ;
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray.Count: " + eventsarray.Count.ToString() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[i].getDate: " + eventsarray[i].getDate() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[i].getTitle: " + eventsarray[i].getTitle() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[i].getPlace: " + eventsarray[i].getPlace() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[i].getDesc: " + eventsarray[i].getDesc() + "\r\n";
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "eventsarray[i].getOrganizer: " + eventsarray[i].getOrganizer() + "\r\n\r\n";
}
```

and the output is like this(input of first event and second event is different):

[image: Output of the for loop]

Before the code of .Add, it is still perfectly fine. I try to use breakpoint to see if there is any loop than make the line run twice, but it run once only. I try to use .Insert(0, eventsarray), but the problem still exist, and the output is exactly the same. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: How do you declare and initialize the _tempe_ variable?

Comment: Maybe *static* is unnecessary.

Comment: Isn't `tempe` added before? I suppose that list holds the same reference twice.

Comment: @Steve it is a global variable events tempe = new events();. I have tried making local like you have suggested, but it is still the same.

Comment: @Ripple it makes no difference. Same result.

Comment: @Steve it is on github now https://github.com/louis993546/temp . thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be explained if the variable `tempe` is a global variable initialized just one time (probably in some point before the add)

If this is the case, when you change the values of the tempe variable, you change the same object referenced in the previous Add. Changing the values don't create another instance of the tempe type. When you readd a second time the variable tempe you have two item in your array but both reference the same object in memory with the values applied in the last update

To fix you just need to:

```
// This creates a new instance of an Events 
Events tempe = new Events();

tempe.setDate(event_info[0]);
tempe.setTitle(event_info[1]);
tempe.setPlace(event_info[2]);
tempe.setDesc(event_info[3]);
tempe.setOrganizer(event_info[4]);
eventsarray.Add(tempe);
```

A part from this there is another error. The code `tempe.setDate(event_info[0]);` seems to set the STATIC variable `date` defined for the class Events. A static variable is shared between all instances of a class. So even if you create a new local variable Events, setting the STATIC date result in all the variables of type Events to have the same value.

You need to change those static variables to instance members.

```
public class Events
{
   private string date;
   private string title;
   private string description;
   private string organizer;
   private string place;

   public void setDate(string newValue)
   {
        date = newValue;
   }
   .... other set methods....
}
```

or change everything and use public properties with getter and setter accessors

```
public class Events
{
   public string Date {get; set;}
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
   public string Organizer {get; set;}
   public string Place {get; set;}
}

....
// This creates a new instance of an Events 
Events tempe = new Events();
tempe.Date = event_info[0];
.....
```